# Unable install mongo 3.6 on raspberry pi

Tags: raspberrypi, mongodb

I've installed Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS on raspberry pi 3 and i'm trying to install [Mongo 3.6](https://fastdl.mongodb.org/linux/mongodb-linux-arm64-ubuntu1604-3.6.4.tgz) on raspberry pi followed steps as per this [link](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-linux/) But i've ended up with following error

```
Cannot execute binary file : Exec Format error
```

The raspberry pi processor is ARMv7l

Comment: the mongodb you were trying to install is a 64 bit version. edit your question and add the output of `uname -a` on raspberry pi

Comment: i couldn't install on Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS but i was able to install on pi64 operating system (github.com/bamarni/pi64/releases])